# Phonegap/android/html if connected to localhotst

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I want to identify how is my mobile device connected to the internet(VIA) home router or 3G or some other router. Depending upon which connection is used I wan a perform the further tasks.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the full documentation [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html).

`(in app/res/xml/config.xml)`

```
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager" />
</feature>
```

`(in app/AndroidManifest.xml)`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Code snippet:

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}

checkConnection();
```